# Synonyms list with confidence score in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a resource/package in python to fetch a list of synonyms with some confidence score. Is something available for such analysis.

For eg.

```
synsets:
  - word: disease
    synonym: disorder
    confidence: 0.9
  - word: ""
    synonym: congenital
    confidence: 0.3
  - word: "abnormality"
    synonym: malformations
    confidence: 0.75
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Why don't you just use a dictionary, e.g: `sym["disease"] = ("disorder", 0.9)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are sort of entering the field of NLP with this question. While there are lexicons that define word polarity, I am not sure if such a mapping for synonyms exists.

The way I would do it is I would use a sentence transformer applied only to words. You will have to vectorize those words and then take note of the cosine of the angle between them.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

x = model.encode("disease")
y = model.encode("disorder")

cos_sim = util.cos_sim(x, y)
print("Similarity:", cos_sim)
```

The above code returns `0.7367` for the `disease, disorder` pair. You can do this with multiple words.